# Custom function with given range and arguments - Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets table:
[Sheet 1 data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2d24.png)

and this function:

```
function loopMovement(movement, variation, range, a, b, c) {
  let arr = [];
  let projection = null;
  for (let i=0; I<=range.length; i++) {
    if (range[i][a]===movement && range[i][b]===variation){
      projection = range[i][c];
      arr.push(projection);
      let maxProjection = Math.max(arr);
    }
  }
  return maxProjection;
}
```

and here is the cell I have in Sheet 2: `=loopMovement(Squat,Competition,Sheet1!A$2:E$7,0,1,4)`. However I am returned an error in the line: `if (range[i][a]===movement && range[i][b]===variation){`: `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined (line 8).`

I tried testing and here are the return values:

1. `Return range.length`:
   `6`
2. `Return range[0][a]`:
   `Squat`
3. `Return range[0][c]`:
   `110`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

```
function loopMovement(movement, variation, range, a, b, c) {
  let arr = [];
  let projection = null;
  for (let i=0; i<range.length; i++) {
    if (range[i][a]===movement && range[i][b]===variation){
      projection = parseFloat(range[i][c]);
      arr.push(projection);
    }
  }
  var maxProjection = arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return Math.max(a, b);
}); 
  return maxProjection; 
}
```

and use the custom function like that:

```
=loopMovement("Squat","Competition",Sheet1!A$2:E$7,0,1,4)
```

## Error:

The error message you are getting:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

has to do with the fact that the for loop iterates through empty rows. According to your screenshot, there are 6 rows excluding the header. However, for loop iterates until row 10.

### Modifications:

I made the following changes to your script:

1. Instead of using the hardcopy value `10`, you can use `range.length`
   to get the total number of rows of the given range.
2. `movement` and `variation` in the formula have to be passed as **strings**:

   ```
   =loopMovement("Squat","Competition",...)
   ```
3. [Math.max()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) does not accept an array as an argument. For
   example, `Math.max(1,5,2)` returns `5`, but `Math.max([1,5,2])`
   returns `NaN`.

   [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) can be used to find the maximum element in a
   numeric array:

   ```
   var maxProjection = arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
   return Math.max(a, b);
   });
   ```
4. The expression `range[i][c]` returns a string with the desired value. However, you want to construct a numeric array, therefore you need to convert it to a float number (given that it might contain decimals) using [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat#:%7E:text=The%20parseFloat()%20function%20parses,returns%20a%20floating%20point%20number.):

   ```
   parseFloat(range[i][c])
   ```